# How to set an argument in a function to False unless the user specifies otherwise?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, typeerror, nameerror

I have a function which contains two arguments. It doesn't really matter what the function does for it self. What it's important that when calling the function I want to set the second argument to a default boolean `False` value.

So let's supose that if the second argument it's `False` or not specified `True` it will print a different line than when it's `True` in the function call.

Here's the thing. I want that the second argument it's set to `False` by default even though when the user specifies it as `False` when calling the function and so, this will be only `True` when the user specifies it.

Example:

```
def example(stringy, printable):
    if printable == True:
        print(stringy, "Printable is set to True")
    else:
        print(stringy, "Printable is set to False")

example("A")
```

The thing is that if I call the function only as `example("Hello World")`, I will get

```
Traceback (most recent call last) line 7, in <module>
    example("A")
TypeError: example() missing 1 required positional argument: 'printable'
```

So is there a way to make printable set to `False` by default unless the user changes it when calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, what you want involves using a keyword argument; these always take a default value. The syntax is almost identical to what you already have:

```py
def example(stringy, printable=False):
    if printable == True:
        print(stringy, "Printable is set to True")
    else:
        print(stringy, "Printable is set to False")
```

The function can then be called any of these ways, with the same result:

```py
example("A")
example("A", False)
example("A", printable=False)
```

Comment: In Python you don't need to explicitly compare things to the value `True`, you can determine it "truthiness" directly — e.g. `if printable:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have only to set the argument with a variable inside the def.

```
def example(stringy, printable = False):
if printable == True:
    print(stringy, "Printable is set to True")
else:
    print(stringy, "Printable is set to False")
```

This will make printable set to False by default unless the user changes it when calling it

```
example("A")
    A Printable is set to False

example("A", True)
    A Printable is set to True
```